# Set border to table tr, works in everything except IE 6 & 7

Tags: html, css, html-table

I set the border for the table event_calendar tr to be red, it works in everything except IE 6 & 7. What is wrong with my CSS?

```
table#event_calendar tr {
    border:1px solid red;
}

<div class="content-body">
<table id="event_calendar">
    <tr class="calendarHeader">
        <th><div class="calendarMonthLinks"><a href="http://webdev.herkimer.edu/calendar/2009/03/">&lt;&lt;</a></div></th>
        <th colspan="5"><h1>April 2009</h1></th>
        <th><div class="calendarMonthLinks"><a class="calendarMonthLinks" href="http://webdev.herkimer.edu/calendar/2009/05/">&gt;&gt;</a></div></th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="calendarDayHeading">Sunday</td>
        <td class="calendarDayHeading">Monday</td>
        <td class="calendarDayHeading">Tuesday</td>
        <td class="calendarDayHeading">Wednesday</td>
        <td class="calendarDayHeading">Thursday</td>
        <td class="calendarDayHeading">Friday</td>
        <td class="calendarDayHeading">Saturday</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: for the record, ie8 and ie9 seem to do this just fine

Answer (score 54, accepted):

IE does not honor the border property for <tr> tags.  However, there are workarounds by putting a top and bottom border around each cell, and using "border-collapse: collapse;" so there's no space between cells.  I will refer to [this resource here](http://csarven.ca/tr-border-trick-for-ie) on the exact method, but it will essentially look like this for you (I haven't tested it myself, so I'm not sure if this is exactly right, but I think you can riff on it.)

```
table#event_calendar {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-right: 1px solid red;
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}

table#event_calendar td, table#event_calendar th {
    border-top: 1px solid red;
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Your CSS is sensible enough, but IE just doesn't do borders on tr elements. If you use this style you should get the intended result though:

```
table#event_calendar {
    border-top:1px solid red;
    border-right:1px solid red;
    border-left:1px solid red;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

table#event_calendar td, table#event_calendar th {
    border-bottom:1px solid red;

}
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot to handle the "th" tags. I hope you don't mind me updating my post to reflect my mistake.

Answer (score 4):

Setting the border on the td is the easiest solution. But if you really really want to make the borders on `<tr>`, you can always set:

```
tr { display:block; border-bottom:1px dotted #F00; }
```

By doing this, you loose the common width between the `<td>`. If you want to make all of them equal on width, set the display for `<td>` to `inline-block` and set some width:

```
td { display:inline-block; width:20%; }
```

It helps when you want to draw some border on the `<td>` and on `<tr>`.

CSS generated content like `tr:before{}` or `tr:after{}` can always help as well.

Comment: This. Setting the `<tr>` tag to `display: block` allowed me to but a border on it.

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS selector to "table#event_calendar tr **td**" and it should work.

Comment: Then he'll get borders on the side of each cell, which is no good.