# Why TR not taking style?

Tags: css, xhtml

CSS

```
table tr {border-bottom:1px solid #008999}
```

HTML

```
<table width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th scope="col">one</th>
         <th scope="col">two</th>
         <th scope="col">three</th>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <th scope="row">Hello</th>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
         <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670424/border-around-specific-rows-in-a-table http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583539/set-border-to-table-tr-works-in-everything-except-ie-6-7 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2238174/border-bottom-for-ie-is-not-working-in-tr

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Add:

```
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Otherwise `tr` [creates no single block](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-CSS2/tables.html#borders).

Simple example:

```css
table
{
  border: 5px solid #900;
  background: #fff;
}
tr
{
  border: 5px solid #090;
}
td
{
  background: #ccc;
  padding: 5px 0;
}

table + table
{
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>def</td>
    <td>ault</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>coll</td>
    <td>apse</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: first of all you found the solution so I'm accepting your answer

Comment: Why does it have to be collapsed? @toscho

Comment: OK, yeah :D - I asked the wrong question :)  What does collapsing the table mean/do?

Comment: @cullub I have added a link to the spec. It is explained with illustrations there.

Answer (score 9):

Try giving

```
table tr th {border-bottom:1px solid #008999}
```

Then you can use

```
table { border-collapse: collapse; }
table tr {border-bottom:1px solid #008999; }
```

See **[The collapsing border model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#collapsing-borders)**

Comment: @metal-gear-solid: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Can you describe the visual result you wish to see?

Comment: @raul - see this `table tr {border-bottom:1px solid #008999}` it means every `TR` in `table` should have border with `1px` height `solid` and in this color `#008999`. What is not clear?

Answer (score 2):

tr by definition wont take border styles. You need to apply it to the td's within it:

```
table tr td {border-bottom:1px solid #008999}
```