# Adding style to CSS Table

Tags: php, css, html-table

I'm echoing data out of my database into a `<table>`, however I'm trying to add a gradient line under each output, to show in-between each `<tr>` output row. But I can't get the CSS right on the `<tr>`.

I've managed to put together the design I want on a `<hr>` here: http://jsfiddle.net/ghrw3k8e/.

But I want it in-between my table rows (not columns).

My PHP output data:

```
echo " <tr> 
<td align='center'>".$1." </td> 
<td align='center'>".$2."</td> 
<td align='center'>".$3."</td>
 </tr> ";
```

Comment: does this answer your question?:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2597694/why-tr-not-taking-style

Comment: possible duplicate of [Border around specific rows in a table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/670424/border-around-specific-rows-in-a-table)

Comment: I think this is not a duplicate question. He wants to draw a gradient border between the rows of a table. The solution here is not to use `outline` on each `<tr>` as you can not draw just the bottom or top part of that `outline`. Collapsing the borders should allow you to set borders on rows, but I think it's not possible to use `border-image` (even if prefixed) to draw a gradient border on a `<tr>`. You can only change the `border-style` value to: `none|hidden|dotted|dashed|solid|double|groove|ridge|inset|outset|initial|inherit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `pseudo-elements`. You will have to put that "border" on one `<td>` of each `<tr>`, so its width should be equal to `100 × number_of_columns %` if they are all the same `width`:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse; 
}

td {
  position:relative;   
  width: 33.333333%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  text-align:center;
}

tr:not(:last-child) > td:first-child::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-1px;
  left:0;
  height: 1px;
  width:300%;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(176,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(176,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(176,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(176,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
  <tr><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr>
  <tr><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td></tr>
</table>
```

Although it may seem more logical to have it on the `<tr>`, it won't get positioned correctly, as you can read from the spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-position

> The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group,
>   table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group,
>   table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements is undefined.

Here's the **incorrect** code. You can see that the `::after` element is positioned at the very bottom of the page:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}


tr{
  position:relative;    
}

td {
  width: 33.333333%;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  text-align: center;
}


tr:not(:last-child)::after {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-1px;
  left:0;
  height: 1px;
  width:300%;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(176,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(176,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(176,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0));
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(176,0,0,.8), rgba(0,0,0,0));
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr><td>A</td><td>B</td><td>C</td></tr>
  <tr><td>D</td><td>E</td><td>F</td></tr>
  <tr><td>G</td><td>H</td><td>I</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I wanted, thank you!! - The only problem I'm facing is it's expanding the width of the second '<tr>' and pushing the 6th & 7th '<tr>' to the side of the element with about 15% of the normal size

Comment: Then you mean `<td>`, not `<tr>`. What `width` have you set the `<td>`s to? In my example it's `33.333333%` because there are 3 of them per row. In your case it should be `100/7 = 14.285714%` or you can also set that in pixels if the table has a fixed width.

Comment: Yeah I got it now, sorry I didn't post, was distracted with the next task at hand, thanks for the reply/help though Dan!! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert an extra row for each line.

```css
hr.soften {
  height: 1px;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(176, 0, 0, .8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(176, 0, 0, .8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(176, 0, 0, .8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(176, 0, 0, .8), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  border: 0;
}
td {
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <hr class="soften" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <hr class="soften" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>A</td>
    <td>B</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is adding only a new column with the '<hr>' embedded.
My output data which I want the line to show inbetween is: 
echo "     <tr>
  <td align='center'>".$1." </td>
  <td align='center'>".$2."</td>
  <td align='center'>".$3."</td>
              </tr> ";

Comment: You should use `position: relative` on the `<td>` containing the `<hr>` and `position: absolute` on the `<hr>` to extend it across all the columns or use the `colspan` attribute on the `<td>`. However, I think that's not entirely semantically correct.