# how do you make a tr border display in IE7?

Tags: html, css

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smacky311/sJw8e/1/)

```
<table>
    <tr style="border:1px solid black"><td>hi</td></tr>
</table>
```

In FF7 I can see the border.  In IE7 I see no border.  How can I display the border for the row?  I would like to avoid having to add borders at the `td` level due to the complexity this adds determining column index for border placement.

Comment: There's no way to fix this. The workaround is, unfortunately, to put the border on the `td`s instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that IE7 is super buggy (as apposed to IE6 which is uber-super buggy).

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/burhans/meVMR/) that demonstrates a possible workaround (top and bottom borders on the TD elements).

Comment: lol, I think you are correct in that going directly to `td` is going to be the only way to accomplish the task.  It sucks to have to find first,last,middle columns to determine what kind of border to insert, but yea IE7 is old as dirt so I guess its to be expected.

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to go directly to `TR`.  Unfortunetly, even though you specified in the question that you would like to avoid `td`, [the workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583539/set-border-to-table-tr-works-in-everything-except-ie-6-7) is to use a `td`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2832260/why-border-of-tr-not-showing-in-ie <- Maybe this helps.....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/583539/set-border-to-table-tr-works-in-everything-except-ie-6-7