# How can I get IE to correctly display the border of my GridView Pager button row?

Tags: asp.net, css, internet-explorer, gridview, border

I have a GridView with pager buttons like this:

```
<PagerSettings Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" FirstPageText="<<" PreviousPageText="<" NextPageText=">" LastPageText=" >>" Position="Bottom" />
```

With pager style set like this:

```
<PagerStyle CssClass="gridPager" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
```

Please take a look at my styles:

```
   .gridPager
   {
       border-collapse: collapse;
       border-width: 1px;
       border-color: Green;
       border-style: solid;   
       font-size: 7pt;
    }

    .gridPager td
    {
        padding-left: 5px;   
    }
```

**The Green Border on my row of Pager buttons is not displaying in Internet Explorer**

I suspect it is because IE doesn't recognize border styles on the **tr** element.

The reason I suspect this is that when I pressed F12 and looked at the IE developer view, I see that the table generated by the GridView created this for the row containing the pager buttons:

```
 <tr class="gridPager" align="right">
    <td colspan="3"><table border="0">
    <tr>
    <td><a href="...pager button links"  </td>
   </tr>
</table></td>
  </tr>
```

Notice the style on the **tr**...

And I found this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/583600/614263

I tried to follow the instructions in that post, but no luck.
It *does* work however, when I make the border-width **2px** or greater.  That's no good though, I need the thin 1px border so that it matches the rest of the grid.

**All i'm trying to do is surround my pager buttons with a border of the same color that is present on the rest of the rows in the grid.**

Please help! How can I achieve this?  This is killing my time!  Thanks!

Comment: How about a class def like `.gridPager > td { border-color: Green }`?

Comment: @AnnL. Thanks much, but didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a different approach. Instead of styling the .gridPager ('tr') tag put your styles on the table instead

```
.gridPager table { ...styles here...}
```

You might have to work with eliminating the padding/margin in the first 'td' before the table, but that should be easily done.

```
.gridPager td { padding: 0; margin: 0; } /* this will affect all td tags */
.gridPager table td { padding-left: 5px; } /* add the padding back to the table td tags */
```

***For me***...I normally style the entire table with a border around the edges except the bottom border. Then I add in the individual rows lines via the 'td' tag. I put the table to GridLines="none".

```
/* this line give the table a border on the three sides - the main grid view table */
.gridTable { border: solid 1px #000; border-width: 1px 1px 0 1px }

/* then I put in the row styles */
.gridTable td { border-bottom: solid 1px #000; }

/* Then I fix the pager styles up with no border on the 'td' tag */
.gridTable table td { border: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks Ekaterina, I will try it later today

Comment: This got me in the right direction.  Thank you so much!   I used the custom styles instead of the Gridlines like you mentioned in the bottom of your answer, but I had to set an ItemStyle for each of the columns in my GridView because on one of the columns I didn't want a right border.

Comment: I am glad you were able to get your view how you wanted.