# Border around tr element doesn't show?

Tags: html, css, html-table

It seems like Chrome/Firefox do not render borders on `tr`, but it renders the border if the selector is `table tr td`.

How can I set a border on a tr ?

My attempt, which doesn't work:

```css
table tr {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Text
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/edi9999/VzPN2/

This is a similar question: [Set border to table tr, works in everything except IE 6 & 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/583539/set-border-to-table-tr-works-in-everything-except-ie-6-7) , but it seems to work everywhere except for IE.

Comment: I'm using firefox and I don't see a border

Answer (score 409, accepted):

Add this to the stylesheet:

```
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKjAX/).

The reason why it behaves this way is actually described pretty well in [the specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders):

> There are two distinct models for setting borders on table cells in
>   CSS. One is most suitable for so-called separated borders around
>   individual cells, the other is suitable for borders that are
>   continuous from one end of the table to the other.

... and later, for `collapse` setting:

> In the collapsing border model, it is possible to specify borders that
>   surround all or part of a cell, row, row group, column, and column
>   group.

Comment: Why exactly was the border hidden ?

Comment: Because that's how `separate` - default - table border model works: you specify borders for each cell. I'll update the answer with quotes from the documentation.

Comment: @edi9999 - I recommend using a reset stylesheet. Check this out [http://www.cssreset.com/](http://www.cssreset.com/)

Comment: The specific explanation to why the border was hidden is this statement in the cited CSS spec, presented as applying in the separated borders model: “Rows, columns, row groups, and column groups cannot have borders (i.e., user agents must ignore the border properties for those elements).”

Comment: Playing with your fiddler example helped, thanks ;)

Answer (score 8):

It is possible to emulate border in table border collapse separate mode with css box-shadow :

```
table tr {
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px #ccc;
}
```