# Table borders not showing up

Tags: html, css, less

I'm trying to style a table and the border isn't showing up. This has never happened to me before, so I'm not sure what to do.

Here's my table:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Dessert (100g serving)</th>
      <th>Calories</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Dessert (100g serving)</td>
      <td>Calories</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And here's my less:

```
@dark-text: rgba(0,0,0,0.87);
@dark-text-secondary: rgba(0,0,0,0.54);
@dark-text-disabled: rgba(0,0,0,0.26);

.table {
    z-index: 10;

    thead {
        tr {
            border-bottom: 3px solid @dark-text-disabled;
            z-index: 10;

            th {
                color: @dark-text-secondary;
                z-index: 10;
            }
        }
    }

    tbody {
        tr {
            border-bottom: 3px solid @dark-text-disabled;
            z-index: 10;

            td {
                z-index: 10;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JdOaVO

Comment: I believe you should style the `td` instead of the `tr`, then `border-collapse: collapse` to get rid of the gaps between rows.

Comment: @Huey If I use Inspect Element in Chrome I can see the highlight of the border, but I can't see it otherwise.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Border around tr element doesn't show?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679020/border-around-tr-element-doesnt-show)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Either move the `border-bottom` rule to the `th` and `td` tags or use [collapsing border model](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp) (`border-collapse: collapse;`) for the .table

```
.table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNmOgg