# markedjs table has no styles

Tags: javascript, css, html-table, javascript-marked

I am using the [markedjs](https://github.com/markedjs/marked) markdown parser on my website, but the table syntax didn't style the right way (no borders and stripes).  My code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Marked in the browser</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>

    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML =
        marked(`
First Header | Second Header
------------ | -------------
Content Cell | Content Cell
Content Cell | Content Cell
        `);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a `marked` issue, but a CSS issue.  Since you are not specifying any styling for your table, you are not getting any :) .

**Edit** [Here](https://github.com/lijundong/markdown-parser) is an example that uses Bootstrap with markedjs.

Non-Bootstrap example:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Marked in the browser</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/marked/marked.min.js"></script>
    <style>
        table { border-collapse: collapse; }
        tr { border-bottom: solid 1px black; }
        tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #f2f2f2;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content"></div>
<script>

    document.getElementById('content').innerHTML =
        marked(`
First Header | Second Header
------------ | -------------
Content Cell | Content Cell
Content Cell | Content Cell
        `);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

- `table { border-collapse: collapse; }` enables per-`tr` borders, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18679047/2877364).
- `tr { ... }` gives you the lines between rows.
- `tr:nth-child(even) { ... }` gives you the shading.

Comment: Thank you. Can I use bootstrap with markedjs, Do I need to add bootstrap class (like "table-striped") to the table tag  dynamically every time after converting markdown to html?

Comment: Edited re. Bootstrap.  As far as adding the bootstrap classes, I would suggest asking a separate question, since that might be more generally applicable.  Based on [this](https://github.com/markedjs/marked/blob/master/docs/USING_PRO.md#user-content-block-level-renderer-methods) and [this](https://github.com/markedjs/marked/issues/334#issuecomment-33571577), I think you need to write a custom renderer.