# Why does the border of tr not show unless the parent table tag has the border-collapse property set to collapse?

Tags: html, css, html-table, border-collapse

html:

```
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
```

css:

```
        table {
            height: 20px;
            width: 30px;
            border: solid 1px;
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        tr {
            border: 1px solid;
        }
```

Here is an image of the table:

[image: rows show borders]

If I comment out `border-collapse: collapse;` under table in the css, the row borders disappear:

[image: rows not showing borders]

In this link:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-collapse there is an example table where the borders are not collapsed(but set to separate, and that doesn't seem to make the borders on my example reappear either):

[image: table example from mozilla]

Here there are gaps between the red and orange borders. Why does my original table not show the row borders at all when the border-collapse property is commented out, instead of showing borders with gaps like in this mozilla example, or something visible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you need to add border to "td".
like :

```css
 tr,td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
```

Comment: That shows something similar to the mozilla example when ```border-collapse: collapse;``` is commented out. It even works without specifying tr css at all. But still I am wondering why having ```border-collapse: collapse;``` with only tr css makes it appear, and without it, the borders disappear.

Comment: i think this can answer your question : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18679020/border-around-tr-element-doesnt-show)

Comment: That link does help, thanks. To quote a comment by Jukka K. Korpela on the top answer from that link: 
`The specific explanation to why the border was hidden is this statement in the cited CSS spec, presented as applying in the separated borders model: “Rows, columns, row groups, and column groups cannot have borders (i.e., user agents must ignore the border properties for those elements).”` So since the separated borders model doesn't show row borders, `tr {
            border: 1px solid;
        }` would never show on the page.